# terminal output in ruby without curses?

Tags: ruby, ncurses

I'm working in Linux ( and konsole if that makes a sifference ) and would like to have some basic control over the screen. What I need is simple and does not need the full power of ncurses, I real need three simple commands, "clear screen", "go to x and y" and "use this color".

Can anyone make suggestions?

Comment: What the problem with ncurses? It's quite strightforward for those three commands you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

To control the screen you need to send (or print) ANSI control sequences.
To clear the screen the sequence is `\e[2J`, which you can just `puts` or `print` to `STDOUT`, depending on your needs.

Some example methods in Ruby:

```
def clear_screen
  print "\e[2J"
end

def clear_line
  print "\e[2K"
end

def reset_cursor
  print "\e[H"
end

def position_cursor(y,x)
  print "\e[#{y};#{x}H"
end

def red
  print "\e[0;31m"
end
```

A table of the sequences is here:
http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php

You can see a table of color sequences here:
http://www.pixelbeat.org/docs/terminal_colours/

Comment: Another helpful blog post to get you started:
http://trainofthought.segfault.gr/2011/11/29/ruby-terminal-manipulation-without-ncurses/